# ¿Es posible actualizar datos automáticamente sin refrescar Activity?

Tags: android, api, kotlin, volley

Estoy consumiendo los datos de un Api Rest desde android usando la librería volley. El código no me está generando ningún error y está mostrando los datos correctamente, pero si uno de los datos cambia en el API es necesario realizar un Refresh para obtener el nuevo dato.

Solo quiero saber si es posible que el cambio se realice automáticamente al detectar un cambio en los datos contenidos en el servicio.

```
 private fun showCompanyRequest(){

        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                val jsonArray = JSONArray(response)
                for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
                    val response = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                    textView.text = response.getString("Nombre_Empresa")

                }
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { textView.text = "That didn't work!" })

        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest)

    }
```

Actualmente este método se encuentra contenido dentro de un SwipeRefreshLayout y el objetivo sea que el cambio se detecte automáticamente y se realice la actualización de la información.

Comment: Ummm tendrás que programar un servicio de sincronización para esto. Eso sí, basándote en las recomendaciones de Android, porque si lo programas mal tu App va a ser desastrosa en el sentido de que un sincronizador mal escrito o mal usado se come la batería y eso no gustará a los usuarios. Otra opción sería Firebase que permite con suma facilidad sincronizar la información en tiempo real.

Comment: Si, he creado funciones para hacer la sincronización y literalmente dañan el funcionamiento de la aplicación, por ahora creo que lo más lógico es mantener el código actual.

Comment: Si por *mantener el código actual*  te refieres a que tiene que ser con Volley, entonces tienes que programar un sincronizador, siguiendo las instrucciones de Android, para que quede optimizado y no se coma la batería. [Aquí tienes un buen punto de partida](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters).

Comment: _tiene que ser con volley_ significa que se puede solucionar de otra forma?

Comment: Se puede solucionar con Firebase, como dije en mi primer comentario. Puedes hacer una prueba y ver si te conviene, las actualizaciones en tiempo real son muy interesantes desde Firebase. Tiene dos escollos: 1º que después de un cierto uso es de pago, pero tiene un plan gratuito muy interesante y si entras al plan de pago será un costo mínimo si tienes bien diseñados los datos: 2º Firebase trabaja con No SQL, por lo que habría que cambiar el concepto tradicional de bases de datos relacionales.